# How can font-ids of internal fonts be retrieved?

Tags: python

An [example](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_4/blf.html#hello-world-text-example) demonstrates the use of the OpenGL Wrapper (bgl) to print text, it loads a font from an external file.

How can a font id of an internaly available font queried?

```
blf.position(font_id, (width * 0.2), (height * 0.3), 0)
blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to query internal fonts, the [documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_6/blf.html) says that 0 as font-id can be used for the default font.

Comment: There's not only the default font with id 0, but also 1 and 2 (mono-spaced fonts), but dunno if their order is guaranteed...